# If $V_{1} \subset V \subset V_1 + V_2\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Is it true $V = V \cap V_{1} + V \cap V_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> Given subspaces $V$, $V_{1}$, $V_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$such that $V_1 \subset V \subset V_1 + V_2$. Is it true $V = V \cap V_{1} + V \cap V_2$?

Could you please verify my proof or propose other ways to solve it?

My proof: since $V_1 \subset V$, $V_1 \cap V = V_1$.

From $V \subset V_1 + V_2$ we know that for $v \in V$, $v_i \in V_i$ the following is true $v = v_1 + v_2$.

Rewrite it as $v - v_1 = v_2$. Hence, $v_2$ should belong to $V$ (meaning $V_2 \subset V)$ and, therefore, $V_1 + V_2 \subset V$.

Combining it with $V \subset V_1 + V_2$, we get $V = V_1 + V_2 = V \cap V_1 + V \cap V_2$.

Comment: @Christoph I thought this way: because $v-v_1$ is a sum of two vectors that belong to $V$. So the sum should belong to $V$

Comment: @Christoph it's in the task :) $V_1 \subset V$. I firstly did not notice that I did not include it in the title but I updated it

Comment: I missed the assumption $V_1\subset V$ in the previous comment. However, the next step is false: "meaning $V_2\subset V$" you have only showed $v_2\in V$ for those $v_2$ appearing in a decomposition $v=v_1+v_2$ for a vector $v\in V$. Not every element of $V_2$ will appear in such a decomposition, so you can't conclude $V_2\subset V$.

Comment: @Christoph ah I see. Then we can reformulate it. Those $v_2$ that appear in the decomposition will belong to $V \cap V_2$. So, now we may conclude $V = V1 + V \cap V_2$. Right?

Comment: Correct, see my new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reach the wrong conclusion $V_2 \subset V$ as an intermediate step.

You approach can be fixed though: The inclusion
$$
V \supset V\cap V_1  + V\cap V_2
$$
is trivial. For the other inclusion, let $v\in V$ and since $V\subset V_1+V_2$ there are $v_1\in V_1\subset V$ and $v_2\in V_2$ such that $v=v_1+v_2$. As you said, this yields $v_2\in V$ and hence $v=v_1+v_2$ with $v_1\in V_1 = V\cap V_1$ and $v_2\in V\cap V_2$. Since this works for any $v\in V$ we get
$$
V \subset V\cap V_1 + V\cap V_2.
$$
Putting together both inclusions we get the desired identity.

Comment: Huge thank you!